# Wordpress set homepage as front page (WP CLI)

Tags: php, wordpress, bash, command-line-interface

I was having issue setting the WordPress home page as front page using WP CLI, I haven't found any solution for this and none of them seems to work it looks like they were outdated.

So first thing you need to do is to list all pages but there is no command to do it directly for exapmle
lets take a look at this command:

```
sudo -u www-data -i wp post list
```

[image: wp post lists]

As you can see it lists only posts but not pages in case we need to use a flag and specify it's parameter:

```
sudo -u www-data -i wp post list --post_type='page'
```

[image: wp posts]

Now we have full lists of all our pages in WordPress site by default. In Left Side you can see each page has a ID so we use that ID to specify our default home page settings not the post_title because also posts content has the same attribute as post_title in first image.

So to switch homepage settings from latest post to static page we use the combination of two following commands:

Home page id

```
sudo -u www-data -i wp option update page_on_front 23
```

Update the page as front page by default.

```
sudo -u www-data -i wp option update show_on_front page
```

Now go check your website settings on Customize -> Homepage Settings.

Done!

Comment: and what is a question here?

Comment: Just a suggestion how to get it done because there was no clear solution how do it.